# Top Down Approach for this dynamic programming problem

Tags: c++, c++14, dynamic-programming

Here is the problem-

You are given array B of size n. You have to construct array A such that 1<=A[i]<=B[i] and sum of the absolute difference of consecutive pairs of A is maximized ,that is, summation of abs(A[i]-A[i-1]) is maximised.You have to return this cost.

Example B=[1,2,3] A can be [1,2,1],[1,1,3],[1,2,3] In all these cases cost is 2 which is the maximum.

Constraints n<=10^5 ,1<=B[i]<=100

Here is my approach -
Cost will be maximum when A[i]=1 or A[i]=B[i]

So I created dp[idx][flag][curr] of size [100002][2][102] where it calculates the cost till index idx. flag will be 0 or 1 representing if A[i] should be 1 or B[i] respectively. curr will be the value of A[i] depending upon flag

Here is my code

```
     #include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define boost ios::sync_with_stdio(false);cin.tie(0);cout.tie(0);
typedef long long int ll;
#define mod 1000000007

 ll n;
ll dp[100002][2][101];
ll b[100005];
 ll solve(ll idx,ll flag,ll curr)
 {

     if(idx>=n)
         return 0;
     ll s1=0;
    if(dp[idx][flag][curr]!=-1)
        return dp[idx][flag][curr];
     if(idx==0)
     {
         int left=solve(idx+1,0,curr);
         int right=solve(idx+1,1,curr);
         return dp[idx][flag][curr]=max(left,right);
     }
     else
     {
         if(flag==0)
         {
             s1=abs(curr-1);
             return dp[idx][flag][curr]=s1+max(solve(idx+1,0,1),solve(idx+1,1,1));
         } 
         else
         {
             s1=abs(b[idx]-curr);
        return dp[idx][flag][curr]=s1+max(solve(idx+1,0,b[idx]),solve(idx+1,1,b[idx]));
         }
     }
 }


int main()
{
    boost
ll t;
cin>>t;
while(t--)
{ 
cin>>n;
memset(dp,-1,sizeof(dp));
ll res=0;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    cin>>b[i];
ll s1=solve(0,0,1);//Starting from idx 0 flag 0 and value as 1
ll s2=solve(0,1,b[0]);//Starting from idx 0 flag 1 and value as B[0]
cout<<max(s1,s2)<<"\n";
}
}'
```

Is there any way to reduce states of dp or any other top down solution because my code fails if values of B[i] are large

Comment: Please don't use "competitive" sites as a learning or teaching resource, because they only teach you really bad habits that will never get you employed (or anyone want to touch your code with a ten-foot pole, really). Get [a few good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282), take classes, learn at least the basics of C++, and some of the common and standard algorithms and data structures. Train, experiment, program, learn. Then you can use such sites as *training* resources instead.

Comment: I am just practicing it . Its good for coding interviews I guess

Comment: Code in the style promoted by such sites (and which you show here) is *not* good for coding interviews. Quite the opposite. That's why you should not use such sites as a beginner to learn programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found the solution using only two states idx and flag

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
typedef long long int ll;

ll n,k;
ll dp[100002][2];
ll b[100005];

ll solve(ll idx,ll flag)
{
    if(idx>=n-1)
        return 0;
    if(dp[idx][flag]!=-1)
        return dp[idx][flag];
    ll val=(flag==1)?b[idx]:1;
    ll left=solve(idx+1,0)+val-1;
    ll right=solve(idx+1,1)+abs(val-b[idx+1]);
    return (dp[idx][flag]=max(left,right));
}

int main()
{ 
ll t;
cin>>t;
while(t--)
{ 
cin>>n;
memset(dp,-1,sizeof(dp));
ll res=0;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    cin>>b[i];
ll s1=solve(0,0);
ll s2=solve(0,1);
cout<<max(s1,s2)<<"\n";
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You implement a recursive approach. Here, a simple iterative implementation allows to get a time efficiency of O(n) and a space efficiency of O(1) 
(not counting the space needed for the input array).

You correctly stated that at index `i`, we have two choices only, `a[i]=1` (flag = 0) or `a[i]=b[i]` (flag = 1)

The basic idea is that, when studying what choice to make at index `i`, we only need to know what are the optimum sums ending at index `i-1`, for flag = 0 (`sum0`) or flag = 1 (`sum1`).

We don't need to explicitely calculate the array `a[.]`.

Note: I kept `long long int` as in your code, but it seems that `int` is quite enough here.

```
#include    <iostream>
#include    <cstdio>
#include    <vector>
#include    <cstdlib>
#include    <algorithm>

#define mod 1000000007          // needed ???

long long int sum_diff (const std::vector<long long> &b) {
    int n = b.size();
    long long int sum0 = 0;
    long long int sum1 = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
        long long int temp = std::max (sum0, sum1 + b[i-1] - 1);            // flag = 0: a[i] = 1
        sum1 = std::max (sum0 + b[i] - 1, sum1 + std::abs(b[i] - b[i-1]));  // flag = 1: a[i] = b[i]
        sum0 = temp;
    }
    return std::max (sum0, sum1);
 }


int main() {
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(0);
    std::cout.tie(0);
    int t;
    std::cin >> t;
    while(t--) { 
        int n;
        std::cin >> n;
        std::vector<long long int> b(n);
        for(int i = 0;i < n; i++) std::cin >> b[i];
        long long int s = sum_diff (b);
        std::cout << s << "\n";
    }
}
```

As you insist to have a top-down (recursive) aproach, I have implement both approaches in the following code. But I insist that the iterative solution is better in this case.

```
#include    <iostream>
#include    <cstdio>
#include    <cstdlib>
#include    <vector>
#include    <algorithm>

int sum_diff (const std::vector<int> &b) {
    int n = b.size();
    int sum0 = 0;
    int sum1 = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
        int temp = std::max (sum0, sum1 + b[i-1] - 1);                      // flag = 0: a[i] = 1
        sum1 = std::max (sum0 + b[i] - 1, sum1 + std::abs(b[i] - b[i-1]));  // flag = 1: a[i] = b[i]
        sum0 = temp;
    }
    return std::max (sum0, sum1);
 }

 void sum_diff_recurs (const std::vector<int> &b, int i, int&sum0, int &sum1) {
    if (i == 0) {
        sum0 = sum1 = 0;
        return;
    }
    sum_diff_recurs (b, i-1, sum0, sum1);
    int temp = std::max (sum0, sum1 + b[i-1] - 1);                      // flag = 0: a[i] = 1
    sum1 = std::max (sum0 + b[i] - 1, sum1 + std::abs(b[i] - b[i-1]));  // flag = 1: a[i] = b[i]
    sum0 = temp;
 }

int main() {
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(0);
    std::cout.tie(0);
    int t;
    std::cin >> t;
    while(t--) { 
        int n, sum0, sum1;
        std::cin >> n;
        std::vector<int> b(n);
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) std::cin >> b[i];
        int s = sum_diff (b);
        std::cout << s << "\n";
        sum_diff_recurs (b, n-1, sum0, sum1);
        std::cout << std::max(sum0, sum1) << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: I know it can be done by bottom up approach. But can you change anything in my recursive solution or provide another top down approach that would be useful.Cuz iterative implementation is hard to think at first

Comment: Note that the algorithm is still recursive: I get index `i` solution from index `i-1` solution.An equivalent recursive implementation (top down) is immediate.

Comment: Please have a look at the new code. Both approaches implemented.

Comment: Ok that is helpful. I will accept your answer. Could you think of any way of changing my top down approach so it will not depend on any one of the states? or its not possible